# Cloud SQL cross-region Replica with CMEK encryption

Tags: google-cloud-sql

The Cloud SQL encryption docs (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/cmek#when_does_interact_with_cmek_keys) state:

> Read replicas from a CMEK-enabled instance inherit CMEK encryption with the same Cloud KMS key as the primary instance.

At the same time:

> Note: The Cloud KMS key ring location must match the region where you want to create a Cloud SQL instance. A multi-region or global region key will not work. A request for creating a Cloud SQL instance fails if the regions don't match.

From these two pieces of information one could conclude that cross region replicas are not possible
to be used alongside CMEK encryption.

However, we've labbed this through by:

- creating a KMS keyring + key in europe-west3 and a Cloud SQL primary instance in europe-west3 using that key
- creating a KMS keyring + key in europe-west2 and a Cloud SQL replica in europe-west2 using the key from europe-west2 (replica for the abovementioned primary)

Can we rely on what we've labbed in practice? Are the docs inaccurrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found on a [different doc page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-cmek#createcmekreplica):

> When you create a read replica of a Cloud SQL instance in the same region, it inherits the same customer-managed encryption key as the parent instance. If you create a read replica in a different region, you are given a new list of customer-managed encryption keys to select from. Each region uses its own set of keys.